# Related questions are over weighted depending on votes

Tags: discussion, related-questions

I have noticed a behavior in the related questions widget. The formula of computing the relation between two questions are heavily depends on votes of the related question. Questions with high amounts of votes have a bigger chance of being listed as related which is, IMO, not correct.

For example, in this question [Reading 8-bit JPEG in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066300/reading-8-bit-jpeg-in-opencv), The first suggestion is: [Image Processing: Algorithm Improvement for 'Coca-Cola Can' Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition?rq=1).

This suggestion has nothing, totally nothing, to do with the reference question. It was listed first just because it is the question with the highest score in OpenCV tag.

Another example is [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array). This question is almost related to any question that talk about array or sorting or any keyword inside this question. Some times I got it as the first related question that because of similar tags between it and the reference question.

Shouldn't the formula of computing the *relation score* treat with votes with less weight? at least something like logarithmic scale where high values will not be over weighted.

Comment: Devil's advocate: if a post gets as many votes as those, obviously a lot of people found it helpful, so even if it is only vaguely related, you will probably find it helpful, too.

Comment: @The_Devil: it looks like advertisement for me rather than helping the user to find an useful post to the problem that they searching for it.

Comment: Hopefully this is something they could get better when/if they ever get the dupe suggestions fixed.

Comment: If the only objective were to match based on relevance, then vote count would be a poor criterion indeed for identifying related questions.  Supposing, then, that the objective is to identify *good* related questions, there is rarely much difference on the goodness scale between a question with score 10 and one with score 100, and even less between one with score 100 and one with score 1000.  If this is not already recognized by means of a cap or a logarithmic scale, then it should be.

Comment: Devil's devil's advocate @CodyGray But helpfulness is determined primarily through topicality. Even if it's a question in the same programming language, if I'm having a scope issue and the related question is about ternary operators, that related question's not gonna be helpful to my problem, no matter how high-quality or highly-voted it is.